# How to fix? Lubuntu had installed to boot partition now "Disk near full"

Tags: lubuntu

On old Dell Dimension 2400, with 40 Gb hard drive and 1 Gb RAM, had installed via USB drive--Lubuntu 14.04 (NO dual boot). Previously had Windows XP, Service Pack 3 on this hard disk.
Obviously, I am not very thorough and did not check to see where Lubuntu had downloaded onto hard disk. Had already downloaded several Lubuntu apps updates in the past, but when trying to set up download for current apps updates, get error message saying disk is almost full. The lightbulb went on and I went to look at disk data.

[image: Disk]
[image: Gparted]

It appears all of Lubuntu is in boot disk.

1. How do I fix this?
2. Why would Lubuntu have installed to boot disk and not into boot AND  extended partitions? (I don't remember the specifics of my install as it was some time ago).

Comment: If you do not have any problem with getting a little techy then may i suggest a method? Also, do you want to keep all your app and data intact and are you sure there aren't any big files in your home directory (it may be hidden) thats taking up all the space.

Comment: Found quick (and easy/dirty solution, depending on your point-of-view). After using commands to remove old kernels, but not freeing enough space on /boot I came across a forum suggestion to use Ubuntu Tweak app. Downloaded it via command line & it worked like a charm after I check-marked option to remove "old kernels." Took it down to 197.93mB unused space. Thanks for all advice comments.